# Bash loop producing unwanted duplicate results

Tags: bash, for-loop, duplicates

I am working in bash.  I am trying to find unique barcodes within strings in a .txt file.  Each string can contain 3 barcodes.  I want to identify and label each unique configuration that contains my barcodes of interest.

This is my starting `reads.txt` file that contains the strings I want to evaluate.

```
ABCD1
EFGH2
ABGH1
EFCD2
```

As an example the barcodes contained in `ABCD1` are `AB`, `CD` and `1`.

My desired result is to identify only srings `ABCD1` and `EFGH2` and to store each of them respectively as `result.1.txt` and `result.2.txt`

Bellow is my attempt.

```
# Add the barcode sequences to a bash array
declare -a BARCODES1=(AB EF)
declare -a BARCODES2=(CD GH)
declare -a BARCODES3=(1 2)

# Initialize counter
count=1

# Search for the barcode sequences in the reads.txt file
rm ROUND*
rm result*

for barcode in "${BARCODES1[@]}";
    do
    grep "$barcode1" reads.txt > ROUND1_MATCHES.txt

        for barcode2 in "${BARCODES2[@]}";
        do
        grep "$barcode2" ROUND1_MATCHES.txt > ROUND2_MATCHES.txt

           for barcode3 in "${BARCODES3[@]}";
            do
            grep "$barcode3" ROUND2_MATCHES.txt > ROUND3_MATCHES.txt

                if [ -s ROUND3_MATCHES.txt ]
                then
                mv ROUND3_MATCHES.txt result.$count.txt
                fi

            count=`expr $count + 1`
            done
        done
    done
```

Strangely this code outputs too many results files. Running `head results*` gives me the following.

```
==> result.1.txt <==
ABCD1

==> result.2.txt <==
EFCD2

==> result.3.txt <==
ABGH1

==> result.4.txt <==
EFGH2

==> result.5.txt <==
ABCD1

==> result.6.txt <==
EFCD2

==> result.7.txt <==
ABGH1

==> result.8.txt <==
EFGH2
```

The desired result would have been

```
==> result.1.txt <==
ABCD1

==> result.2.txt <==
EFCD2
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why in bash specifically?

Comment: I used bash because it works nicely on the linux cluster environment that I am using and because i am more comfortable writing bash scripts than other languages (i am still a beginner).  Certainly something in python could be made to work. Is there an obvious advantage (speed etc) that I am missing out on by choosing to use bash?

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Don't know, just seems overly-complex and disk-heavy to keep grepping/etc instead of using a more general-purpose language with better string support etc.

Comment: Using `grep` inside a nested inner loop (starting a whole new program, reading the input file from the very beginning, etc) is indeed a serious code smell. That's not necessarily a problem with bash, though, as opposed to a problem with how it's being applied.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to iterate over the *indices* of the arrays:

```
for index in "${!BARCODES1[@]}"; do
    echo "${BARCODES1[index]}${BARCODES2[index]}${BARCODES3[index]}"
done
```

```
ABCD1
EFGH2
```

With 3 *nested* loops, `count` gets incremented 2 * 2 *2 = 8 times

---

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do: If you're trying to generate the cross product of (AB,EF) and (CD,GH) and (1,2), you can do

```
$ printf "%s\n" {AB,EF}{CD,GH}{1,2}
ABCD1
ABCD2
ABGH1
ABGH2
EFCD1
EFCD2
EFGH1
EFGH2
```

And then, if you are trying to extract the lines in reads.txt that match one of those strings, then

```
$ grep -xFf <( printf "%s\n" {AB,EF}{CD,GH}{1,2} ) reads.txt
ABCD1
EFGH2
ABGH1
EFCD2
```